# How to build GStreamer 1.20.1 from source on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: github, gstreamer, ubuntu-20.04, meson-build

For a video streaming project, I need to install GStreamer version 1.20.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.

If I install the latest stable release from [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c) then it will install the version 1.16.2. So, I need to build it from source to get the required version. The official documentation has two different ways of building from source.

I first built using [Cerbero](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/building-from-source-using-cerbero.html?gi-language=c) after git checkouting to 1.20.1 but after finishing the installation process, it still shows that the stable version (1.16.2) has been installed.

Then I tried the other method using [Meson](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/building-from-source-using-meson.html?gi-language=c)

However, it keeps going and it seems to be in a loop. The last two lines in the screenshot are repeated every few minutes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling the native Gstreamer before installing from source?
`sudo apt-get remove *gstreamer*`
If you don't remove this, then you will have two gstreamer instances and it will show two versions. Be careful though, because ubuntu-desktop depends upon gstreamer and you could accidentaly mess up your Ubuntu installation.